# jQuery UI tooltip is stuck open when the source DOM element moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have a div that contains a few thumbnails which can be dragged and dropped.  When one thumbnail is dropped over top of another thumbnail, they switch places.  I do this using AngularJS and manipulating the underlying data on the $scope.

Anyway, here's the problem:

The thumbnails have tooltips that open when I hover over them.  When I click and start dragging a thumbnail (let's call this one the source thumbnail), its tooltip disappears (as it should).  So far so good.  When I drop the thumbnail over top of the other, however, there's a brief moment where the *target* thumbnail's tooltip appears, since the mouse is currently hovering over the target tooltip.

A split second later, the underlying model swaps the two pieces of data, and the DOM updates to reflect the change - effectively swapping the two thumbnails.  Now, the target's tooltip is STILL open, but my mouse is no longer over the target, because it was just swapped!  The tooltip will remain open until I re-trigger the tooltip events at the new location.

This behaviour is observed roughly 50% of the time, but I can artificially reproduce it 100% of the time by adding a short (~1 second) delay before changing the underlying data, causing the thumbnails to switch places.

NOTE: This problem does NOT occur in Chrome, but it does in Firefox and IE.  I haven't tried Safari.

Has anyone experienced this problem, or something similar?  Please let me know if I can provide any further details.  Thanks!

Edit:  Here's a jsfiddle example that illustrates the problem:  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uHuDp/257/)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.widget.bridge('uitooltip', $.ui.tooltip);
    </script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ContentController">
        <div class="indent">
            <div ng-repeat="square in squares" style="width: 400px">
                <item data="square" helper="helperFunction"></item>
            </div>
            Drag the top box onto the bottom box and keep the mouse cursor stationary for ~1 second.  The tooltip will be stuck open when the boxes switch places.  Dragging the bottom box to the top box, however, does not have this problem.
            <br><br>
            Also, this problem seems to only be present in Firefox and IE.  Chrome works as expected.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the default browser tooltips with the jquery version:

```
$('*').tooltip({track: true});
```

Then you could set the tooltips to be disabled while you drag your elements:

```
$('.thumbnail').tooltip('disable');
```

On drop, enable them again:

```
$('.thumbnail').tooltip('enable');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uHuDp/1/

Edit: for your example:

```
 $(element).find("span.item-outer").uitooltip('disable');
 $(element).find("span.item-outer").uitooltip('enable');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uHuDp/260/

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I follow you here.  Here's a live example of what I'm describing:  http://jsfiddle.net/uHuDp/257/

Comment: While your change does appear to fix the behaviour in the contrived jsfiddle example, it doesn't fix the problem in my actual code.  It's still possible to break your jsfiddle fix if you do the following:  Drag the bottom square over the top square, and then quickly move your mouse back to the bottom square again before it has a chance to swap.  The tooltip is still stuck open.  This isn't the exact problem that I experience in my code, but I believe it is tangentially related.  I can't help but wonder if the problem is somehow related to how Firefox resolves the ordering of multiple events...